# How to implement automatic re-authorization in redux toolkit query?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I have been trying to implement automatic re-authorization but anytime I try accessing the API endpoint`("/refresh")` to get a new access token, it sends back this error

```
error:
data: "Forbidden"
error: "SyntaxError: Unexpected token F in JSON at position 0"
originalStatus: 403
status: "PARSING_ERROR"
```

. I tried doing the same thing with axios and it worked, it returned back the access token, the endpoint even works when I use insomnia Api client too.

Here is my code

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react'
import { setCredentials, logOut } from '../component-slice'

const baseQuery = fetchBaseQuery({
  baseUrl: "http://localhost:5000/api", 

  credentials: 'include',
  prepareHeaders: (headers, { getState }) => {
    const token = getState().componentSlice.token
    if (token) {
      headers.set('authorization', `Bearer ${token}`)
    }
    return headers
  }
})
const baseQueryWithReauth = async (args, api, extraOptions) => {
  let result = await baseQuery(args, api, extraOptions)

  if (result?.error?.originalStatus === 403) {
    console.log('sending refresh token')
    // send refresh token to get new access token
    const refreshResult = await baseQuery('/refresh', api, extraOptions)
    console.log(refreshResult)
    if (refreshResult?.data) {
      const user = api.getState().componentSlice.user
      // store the new token
      api.dispatch(setCredentials({ ...refreshResult.data, user }))
      // retry the original query with new access token
      result = await baseQuery(args, api, extraOptions)
    } else {
      api.dispatch(logOut())
    }
  }

  return result
}

export const userApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'api',
  baseQuery: baseQueryWithReauth,
  tagTypes: ['Product', 'List', 'category'],
  endpoints: builder => ({
    getProfile: builder.mutation({
      query: () => ({ url: `/profile`, credentials: 'include', method: 'GET' })
    }),
   
    googleLogout: builder.mutation({
      query: () => ({
        url: `/google/logout`,
        method: 'GET',
        credentials: 'include'
      })
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: It seems your `refresh` endpoint does not return a JSON response, but a string?

Comment: it returns a JSON response

Comment: You are getting a 403 error by the server and it does not return `{ status: "Forbidden" }` or something, but it returns the word `Forbidden`, which is not JSON-parseable, hence the error.

Comment: Ohh, that’s because I’m just logging the server error. It actually returns back ’{ status : “forbidden”}‘

Answer (score 2):

RTK query automatically stores the data in the redux store for 1min as a 'cache' by default instead of re-fetching the data again from the server when it is needed. it turns out my refresh token expires within the same timeframe the data is being cached. So when I try to access the `"/refresh"` endpoint I get a 403(forbidden) error simply because my `Jwt token` had already expired.

FIX: I just had to increase the expiry time of the `Jwt token`.